# how to generate the series with the increment of 0.50

Tags: c#

I have a series of numbers like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
and i want to generate a series with increment of 0.5
the result should be 0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.5 and so on

is there any simple way to calculate it by math.round

Comment: `for loop ... i * 0.5` no need for math.round

Comment: You should explain more what you want to achieve, For example, you have number 2. What rules you want apply to get 1.5 or 2.0 or 2.5 or anything else?

Comment: sorry I am updating my question.in my database table xyz I have two fields abc and pqr.abc is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8    and pqr is 12.11,13.13,14.12,15.12,16.14,17.12,18.21,19.12   .now I want to fetch the records by the increment of .5 .for example if 1 then 12.11,1.5 then avgof pqr for 1 and 2.and want to do this linq query.please help

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 0;
while(true) yield return x += 0.5;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `Math.Round` it is not possbile. But:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> Serie()
{
   float val = 0f;
   while (true)
   {
      val += 0.5;
      yield return val;
   }  
}
```

Warning: that method is inifited, co take care (f.e calling `ToList()` is not a good thing). You can also pass optional parameter to limit results.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted... I have countered.

Comment: Also don't know why. Thanks! Downwotes without comment are brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't need math.round

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
List<decimal> result = numbers.Select(x => (decimal)x / 2).ToList();
```

or

```
List<decimal> result2 = numbers.Select(x => (decimal)x + 0.5m).ToList();
```

what ever your rule should be

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method. This method needs a `IEnumerable<int>` as input, and then returns an `IEnumerable<double>` with the halfs merged into them.

```
IEnumerable<double> GetListWithHalfs(IEnumerable<int> inputList)
{
    IEnumerable<double> halfList = inputList.Select(i => i - 0.5);
    return inputList.Zip(halfList, (full, half) => new double[] { half, full }).SelectMany(d => d);
}
```

Use it like:

```
IEnumerable<int> originalList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
IEnumerable<double> includingHalfs = GetListWithHalfs(originalList);

foreach(var number in includingHalfs)
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Output:

> 0,5
>   1
>   1,5
>   2
>   2,5
>   3
>   3,5
>   4
>   4,5
>   5
>   5,5
>   6
>   6,5
>   7
>   7,5
>   8
>   8,5
>   9
>   9,5
>   10

Or you could inline everything so you can use it without the method:

```
var inputList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
var result = inputList.Zip(inputList.Select(i => i - 0.5), (full, half) => new double[] { half, full }).SelectMany(d => d);
```